# Equivalent of AspectJ call pointcut in PostSharp

Tags: aspectj, postsharp

Is there an equivalent of the AspectJ call pointcut in PostSharp?

Concrete: Both ClassA and ClassB call method foo() on ClassC. I want to intercept calls only from A to C, NOT B to C. In AspectJ this can be achieved by pairing the call with the within pointcut like this:

call(* ClassC.foo()) && within(ClassA)

How would i achieve this in PostSharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible directly as MethodInterceptionAspect applies to a method itself not to a call site and as such the pointcut will be only able to filter methods, not call sites.

Possible solution would be to have two aspects that cooperate - one would manage a thread-static variable, the second one would either execute the intercepted method or do some additional work. However, this is not an ideal solution.

Comment: So there is absolutely no way to weave at call sites in PostSharp? I thought of using a threadsafe switch, but i would like to weave code at the call site instead of the destination, due to the fact that most of the target methods are in 3rd party assemblies.

Comment: What I'm describing is the concept. Pointcuts (yes, the definition is slightly different from AspectJ) are providing metadata declarations on which the aspect should be applied. Surely, when you apply an aspect to a method that is declared in other assembly, the transformation is done at call-site level because it is the only option.

Comment: So, postsharp Will apply the aspect at the call site when I apply the an aspect to a referenced assembly?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And if it is declared in the transformed assembly, it will transform the method itself.

Comment: I thought this solved the problem, but now i want to intercept method calls to an interface. The implementation of the interface is generated using dynamic proxy, is there any solution within PostSharp for this scenario?

Comment: Well you can do that using multicasting like this: `[assembly: TestInterceptionAspect(AttributeTargetAssemblies = "mscorlib", AttributeTargetTypes = "System.IDisposable", AttributeInheritance = MulticastInheritance.Strict)]`. Note that we fixed this recently and it didn't work before 3.1.52 and 4.0.32 (so you need the latest version) and it is not possible to do this using `IAspectProvider`.

Comment: Can I also do this on interfaces from the declaring assembly?